# SublimeLinter 3 Not Working

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

I've been having some problems with SublimeLinter3. I recently installed JSHint and Sublime Linter 3 with my package control, and when I manually use JSHint from the command palette it works fine. However, my SublimeLinter isn't doing anything. Shouldn't it provide instant visual feedback when i type errors and save a file? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you installed the [`SublimeLinter-jshint`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-jshint) package, and not the one just named `JSHint`, as it doesn't work with SublimeLinter. Also, make sure you've completely read through the [SublimeLinter documentation](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) so that everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Hey, I've managed to solve the problem. For some reason, `npm install -g jshint` was not working for me. The problem was fixed when i used `sudo npm install -g jshint`. While I don't know why I had to do that, I'm just happy it ended up working.

Comment: i tried many solutions but didn't worked for and now i use https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint in ST3 and problem solved. Once you install plugin CTRL+SHIFT+P and jshint: set plugin options and make this line true "lint_on_save": true and restart ST

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [installation documentation](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint) ?
You have to install jshint using Node.js

If you have done every steps, take a look at Tools > SublimeLinter > Lint Mode.
"Background" should be selected if you want a syntax check as you are typing.

You can also try to make some errors and press CTRL+K and then A to show all errors. If you see errors that means jshint is correctly installed and working. If not you have a problem with your installation.

Comment: Hey, I've managed to solve the problem. For some reason, `npm install -g jshint` was not working for me. The problem was fixed when i used `sudo npm install -g jshint`. While I don't know why I had to do that, I'm just happy it ended up working.